# Calling conj() function on every element of a C++ complex vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

If I execute this code:

```
vector<complex<double> >
idft( vector<complex<double> > * v)
{

    for_each(v->begin(), v->end(), conj);
```

then compiler gives me following error:

```
dft.cpp: In function 'std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > > idft(std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >*)':
dft.cpp:38: error: no matching function for call to 'for_each(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::complex<double>*, std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::complex<double>*, std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

If I apply conj() for just one element then it works fine:

```
vector<complex<double> >
idft( vector<complex<double> > * v)
{

    conj(v->at(0));
```

How can I apply conj() for whole vector without using loop?

Comment: I suspect your conj method is not taking an iterator as a parameter. To make your question clearer please add the signature for the conj method.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/conj/

Comment: Have you tried with a range-based for?

Comment: No I have not tried. I thought that that using for_each would be easier

Comment: @siphr conj should take a reference, not an iterator.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks! Yes. I figured that out once I was able to lookup the method in the reference.

Comment: To be clear, do you want the result of conjugation to be applied to the vector? (All the answers posted so far do call `conj` for each element but without updating the vector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for_each` is rarely a good idea in modern (C++11 and beyond) C++.

```
void idft( std::vector<std::complex<double> >& v)
{
  for (auto& x : v)
    x = std::conj(x);
}
```

or even:

```
template<class Range>
void idft( Range& v)
{
  for (auto& x : v)
    x = std::conj(x);
}
```

is clean, generic, correct, and easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

The answer that was selected (now it's changed) with `for_each` is ***absolutely*** wrong. You can't use `for_each` because it doesn't modify the object you're iterating on. Here's how to do this using `std::transform` and a simple lambda function.

```
std::transform(v->begin(),v->end(), v->begin(), [](const std::complex<double>& c) -> std::complex<double> { return std::conj(c); });
```

Comment: moreover, it should be: `std::transform(v.begin(),v.end(), v.begin(), [](const std::complex<double>& c) -> std::complex<double> { return std::conj(c); });` (with const)

Comment: @foxfireee It's not necessary, but it's a good practice. Thank you, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Because [`std::conj`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/conj) has several template function overloads, compiler don't know which one should be selected according to the function name only.

> ```
> template< class T >
> complex<T> conj( const complex<T>& z );       (1)     
> template< class DoubleOrIngeter >
> std::complex<double> conj( DoubleOrInteger z );       (3)     (since C++11)
> ```

You could

```
typedef complex<double> (*CONJ_TYPE)( const complex<double>& z );
for_each(v->begin(), v->end(), static_cast<CONJ_TYPE>(conj<double>));
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/ZQBD69395)

Answer (score 0):

Use std::transform if your function (conj) does not modify its input arg.